# Grep chromosome patterns from a file

Tags: awk, grep

I have a pattern which are chromosome coordinates such as:

`chr1    1000    2000    chr1    11000   12000`

For a single pattern, I am using the following query:

```
grep 'chr1\s\+1000\s\+2000\s\+chr1\s\+11000\s\+12000' DB_file.txt
```

For a complete list of such patterns, I have a query file:

```
cat query.txt
chr1\s\+1000\s\+2000\s\+chr1\s\+10000\s\+11000
chr1\s\+1000\s\+2000\s\+chr1\s\+14000\s\+15000
chr1\s\+1000\s\+2000\s\+chr1\s\+175000\s\+176000
chr1\s\+1000\s\+2000\s\+chr1\s\+1639000\s\+1640000
```

How can I do this ? grep -f is taking too long. Thanks

example for the DB_file.txt

```
chr1    1000    2000    chr1    10000   11000   3   281 0   0.459585414218248   0   0   0   1218    1   1.88650643678468    0   0   0   0.000000425582664277006 3.87833663319237    0.000000425597761316606 0.201115300038799   0.743522481235195   0.822936566866982
chr1    1000    2000    chr1    11000   12000   4   281 0   0.459585414218248   0   0   0   459 1   0.710924839477969   0   0   0   0.000000355375953311341 1.75327208538672    0.000000192399150742434 0.068194541602096   0.101318817290739   0.81707019750747
chr1    1000    2000    chr1    12000   13000   5   281 0   0.459585414218248   0   0   0   1415    1   2.19163104109222    0   0   0   0.000000310867653966458 3.44281554060217    0.000000377804900731428 0.128881860609444   0.263803805858084   0.81707019750747
chr1    1000    2000    chr1    13000   14000   1   281 0   0.459585414218248   0   0   0   437 1   0.676850010570529   0   0   0   0.000000285200375223444 1.49690344452761    0.000000164265976667856 0.335040184988013   0.776177861586765   0.837324774202159
chr1    1000    2000    chr1    14000   15000   1   281 0   0.459585414218248   0   0   0   530 1   0.820893605497437   0   0   0   0.000000271516726063383 1.60662404023105    0.000000176306406449545 0.322230259464951   0.799436461434159   0.850447555722604
chr1    1000    2000    chr1    16000   17000   1   281 0   0.459585414218248   0   0   0   490 1   0.758939371120272   0   0   0   0.000000253854147173018 1.41695624386548    0.000000155492795574155 0.343542270137564   0.75754917047966    0.828368055880824
chr1    1000    2000    chr1    18000   19000   2   281 0   0.459585414218248   0   0   0   130 1   0.201351261725787   0   0   0   0.000000231422263301451 0.691389012939271   0.0000000758710869983566    0.119714987783608   0.152817308925748   0.81707019750747
```

EDIT: The  DB_file.txt is huge with 4636593 lines because of which grep is taking too long. How can I speed up ? Thanks

Comment: Then, `grep  -f  query.txt  DB_file.txt` works, right? I got `chr1    1000    2000    chr1    10000   11000   3   281 0   0.459585414218248   0   0   0   1218    1   1.88650643678468    0   0   0   0.000000425582664277006 3.87833663319237    0.000000425597761316606 0.201115300038799   0.743522481235195   0.822936566866982` and `chr1    1000    2000    chr1    14000   15000   1   281 0   0.459585414218248   0   0   0   530 1   0.820893605497437   0   0   0   0.000000271516726063383 1.60662404023105    0.000000176306406449545 0.322230259464951   0.799436461434159   0.850447555722604`

Comment: Actually, my DB_File is a very large file (4636593 lines). When I am using grep, its taking very very long time. Is there a way I can speed up ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the fields in your `DB_File.txt` are separated by tabs and not arbitrary whitespace. If that's the case, if you change your `query.txt` file to use TSV data instead, you can use

```
grep -Ff query.txt DB_File.txt
```

which should be faster than the regular expression version.

To change your existing `query.txt` file to use literal tabs:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\Q\s\+/\t/g' query.txt
```

If you're going to be using this data file a lot, another option is to import it into a sqlite database (Or postgres or whatever), and query it with SQL after creating the appropriate indexes so the whole table doesn't have to be scanned.